# Error while Reading rtf file content

Tags: java

I am getting the following error while extracting content from a RTF file.

> javax.swing.text.rtf.RTFReader$AttributeTrackingDestination.handleKeyword(RTFReader.java:1279)

### code for extraction

```
JEditorPane p = null;
EditorKit rtfKit = null;
EditorKit txtKit = null;
Writer writer = null;
int[] filesCount = null;
try {

    p = new JEditorPane();
    p.setContentType("text/rtf");
    rtfKit =   p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/rtf");
    rtfKit.read(new FileReader(fileName), p.getDocument(), 0);

    rtfKit = null;

    txtKit = p.getEditorKitForContentType("text/plain");
    writer = new StringWriter();
    txtKit.write(writer, p.getDocument(), 0,   p.getDocument().getLength());
    String paragraphs = writer.toString();
```

Comment: You forgot to mention which exception was called

Comment: Or which line of your code triggered the exception.